# Python re.compile, split string into two while preserving delimiter

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to split strings with a common delimiter into two separate strings. I'm unsure if regex is the right choice, but `.split, sep` seems to target words and mine will always be different as provided below.

The main problem to my current approach is that I can't account for when the name isn't assigned between `( )`. In cases where there is no `(Name)` descriptor I would still want a foo/foo[1] strings.

I'm also not currently returning the `)` delimiter in the string which I want to preserve. Should I create two re.groups and then split or is there a more simplistic way to approach this?

*Sample strings*

```
s1 = '(NTUSER.DAT) Checks for IOCs for Clampi (per Trend Micro)'
s2 = '(NTUSER.DAT) Autostart - get Command Processor\AutoRun value from NTUSER.DAT hive'
s3 = '(All) Parse hive, print deleted keys/values'
s4 = '(NTUSER.DAT;Software) Get IE Zone settings'
s5 = 'Gets users Startup Folder location'
```

*Desired output*

```
'Name', 'Text'  #E.g. (NTUSER.DAT), Checks for IOCs for Clampi (per Trend Micro)
```

*I've tried*

```
foo = re.compile("[)]").split(string) #this doesn't preserve the ")" on output
```

Comment: I think you want to `match`, not to `split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in this way

```
>>> foo = re.compile(r'(?<=^\(NTUSER\.DAT\)) |(?<=^\(All\)) |(?<=^\(NTUSER\.DAT;Software\)) |(?<=^\( \)) ')
```

Unfortunately, `Name`s in `(...)`s you have to write them all manually  since`lookbehind` doesn't allow using quantifier.

```
>>> foo.split(s1)
['(NTUSER.DAT)', 'Checks for IOCs for Clampi (per Trend Micro)']
>>> foo.split(s2)
['(NTUSER.DAT)', 'Autostart - get Command Processor\\AutoRun value from NTUSER.DAT hive']
>>> foo.split(s3)
['(All)', 'Parse hive, print deleted keys/values']
>>> foo.split(s4)
['(NTUSER.DAT;Software)', 'Get IE Zone settings']
>>> foo.split('( ) abcde')                                                          
['( )', 'abcde']
```

Anyway as @Andrea Corbellini already mentioned. It much more simple if you use `match()` instead of `split()`.

e.g.

```
>>> foo = re.compile(r'^(\(.*?\)) (.*)$')
>>> result = foo.match(s1)
>>> result.group(1) + ', ' + result.group(2)
'(NTUSER.DAT), Checks for IOCs for Clampi (per Trend Micro)'
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to just use `str.split` with a max split and then add back the `')'` to the first string.

```
res = s1.split(')', 1)
res[0] += ')'
```

Comment: No, it just wouldn't split the string and you'd get a list of one element.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

```
get_foo = re.compile(r'([^\)]*\)?)').findall

foo = get_foo(s1)
# And so on
```